# How to enable TinyMCE custom formats in gutenberg classic editor block?

Tags: php, wordpress, styles, tinymce, wordpress-gutenberg

I used to add custom styles/formats to TinyMCE, like this:

```
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'add_tinymce_formats', 10, 2);
function add_tinymce_formats($mceinit, $editor_id){

  $new_styles = array(
    array(
      'title' => 'Foradori'
      ,'items' => array(
        array(
          'inline' => 'span',
          'title' => 'Red',
          'classes' => 'red'
        )
      )// end items
    )// and main array
  );

  $mceinit['style_formats_merge'] = true;
  $mceinit['style_formats'] = json_encode($new_styles);
  return $mceinit;
}


add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_editor_styles' );
function add_editor_styles(){
  add_editor_style('css/tinymce-editor.css');
}
```

But now with gutenberg, they won't be added to the classic editor block.
Is there any solution?